# Compare two lists and write the result in a file using the rejectattr file

Tags: ansible, ssl-certificate, build-automation, ansible-2.x, netscaler

Given the list `expired`:

```json
[
    {
        "cert": "help.abc.com.cer",
        "certkey": "help.abc.com-key",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "help.abc.com.key"
    },
    {
        "cert": "prod.abc.ca-2020.cer",
        "certkey": "prod.abc.ca",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "prod.abc.ca-2020.key"
    },
    {
        "cert": "ca-profile-service-prod.abc.com.cer",
        "certkey": "ca-profile-service-prod-cert",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "ca-profile-service-prod.abc.com.key"
    },
    {
        "cert": "eclosing.abc.com.cer",
        "certkey": "eclosing-cert",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "eclosing.abc.com.key"
    },
    {
        "cert": "merlin-ldp-stg.abc.com.cer",
        "certkey": "merlin-ldp-stg.cert",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "merlin-ldp-stg.abc.com.key"
    },
    {
        "cert": "stg-abc.services.cer",
        "certkey": "stg-abc.services.cert",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "stg-abc.services.key"
    },
    {
        "cert": "fintech-ap-stg.cer",
        "certkey": "fintech-ap-stg-cer",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "fintech-ap-stg.key"
    },
    {
        "cert": "docker.prod.abc.com_2021.cer",
        "certkey": "docker.prod.abc.com",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "docker.prod.abc.com_2021.key"
    },
    {
        "cert": "merlin-ldp.cert-2023",
        "certkey": "merlin-ldp.cert-2023",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "merlin-ldp.cert-2023"
    },
    {
        "cert": "abc-net-etc-2023",
        "certkey": "abc-net-etc-2023",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "abc-net-etc-2023"
    },
    {
        "cert": "ppc01.abc.com_2024.cer",
        "certkey": "ppc01.abc-2024",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "key": "ppc01.abc_2024.key"
    }
]
```

And the list `certkey_binding`

```json
[
    {
        "certkey": "help.abc.com-key",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "dfw-xyz.help.abc.com-SSL_tcp443-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "prod.abc.ca",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "cca-canada.dfw.prod.abc.com-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "ca-profile-service-prod-cert",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "dfw-ca-profile-service-prod.abc.com_ssl_443_lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "eclosing-cert",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "eclosing.dfw.abc.com-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "merlin-ldp-stg.cert",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "dfw.merlin-ldp-stg.abc.com-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "stg-abc.services.cert",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "stg-abc.services.abc.com-DFW-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "fintech-ap-stg-cer",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "dfw-fintech-ap-stg.abc.com-HTTPS_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "docker.prod.abc.com",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "dfw-thirdparty.docker.prod.abc.com-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "docker.prod.abc.com",
        "data": "2",
        "servername": "dfw-us.gcr.docker.abc.com-SSL_tcp443-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "docker.prod.abc.com",
        "data": "3",
        "servername": "dfw-elasticsearch.prod.abc.com-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "merlin-ldp.cert-2023",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "merlin-ldp.merlin-ldp-DFW-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "abc-net-etc-2023",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "abc-net-etc.dfw.prod.abc.com-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    },
    {
        "certkey": "ppc01.abc-2024",
        "data": "1",
        "servername": "dfw-clho.abc.com-SSL_443tcp-lb",
        "stateflag": "2",
        "version": 2
    }
]
```

I try to compare the given lists and reject any `certkey` in the list `expired` that is associated with server name in the list `certkey_binding`.

My Ansible playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: citrix_adc
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: Filter expired certs with no binding
      set_fact:
        filtered_certs: "{{ expired | rejectattr('certkey','equalto',item.certkey) | list }}"
      loop: "{{ certkey_binding }}"
      
    - name: Write filtered certs into file
      copy:
        content: "{{ filtered_certs | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: '/Users/abcdef/Downloads/Ansible_Automation/NS_Cert_Cleanup/Certkeys_To_Delete.json'
```

Ideally I am expecting that `filtered_certs` should be an empty list, as all of the `certkey`s have a server name associated with them. But, in the result, I am seeing all the `certkeys` from the list `expired`.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You are simply reassigning your loop only filtering one element out, by the fact you are using a loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in a single task.

1. define a list of certificate keys in the list `certkey_binding`, using a [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) filter
2. Use that list in combination of `rejectattr`, but, with the [`in`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-tests.in) test, rather, to exclude any certificate key in the list `expired` that would also be present in the list `certkey_binding`
3. Then use the result in the task itself

So, your task ends up being:

```yaml
- copy:
    dest: example.json
    content: >-
      {{
        expired
          | rejectattr(
              'certkey','in', certkey_binding | map(attribute="certkey")
            )
          | to_nice_json
      }}
```